# Animating the removal of an array object with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, react-transition-group

I am trying to get an animation (for now a fade) to play when clicking on the x of the chip. I have been able to hack together a fade in, so when I enter a new name, it fades in on arrival.

Now, I noticed the animation wouldn't play on exit (and I figured it was because its reference was being removed from the array, and that affected the call of `map()`). Really what I want to do is have the object animate away, and then be removed from the array.

When I try using a `setTimeout` to wait for the animation to complete, it starts applying the animation to neighboring elements in the array.

I do know why this is happening, but I simply do not know how to shift my code into the react paradigm and out of my stack/callback mindset and set up react to do what I'm asking it to.

```
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Chip from '@mui/material/Chip';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Transition } from 'react-transition-group';

const startList = [
  { name: "Ethan Anderson" },
  { name: "Olivia Brooks" },
  { name: "Mason Carter" },
  { name: "Ava Davis" }
];

function Student({ student, hDelete }) {
  const nodeRef = useRef(null);
  const [inProp, setIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIn(true);
  }, [] );

  const handleDelete = () => {
    setIn(false);
    setTimeout(() => hDelete(student), 320)
  }

  const duration = 300;

  const defaultStyle = {
    transition: `opacity ${duration}ms ease-in-out`,
    opacity: 0,
  }

  const transitionStyles = {
    entering: { opacity: 1 },
    entered:  { opacity: 1 },
    exiting:  { opacity: 0 },
    exited:  { opacity: 0 },
  };

  return (
    <Transition
      nodeRef={nodeRef}
      in={inProp}
      appear="true"
      timeout={duration}
    >
      {state => (
        <ListItem style={{ ...defaultStyle, ...transitionStyles[state] }}>
          <Chip
            variant="solid"
            size="small"
            sx={{
              height: 'auto',
              '& .MuiChip-label': {
                display: 'block',
                whiteSpace: 'normal',
              },
            }}
            label={`${student.name}`}
            onDelete={handleDelete}
          />
        </ListItem>
      )}
    </Transition>
  )
}

const ListItem = styled('li')(({ theme }) => ({
  margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
}));

export default function CreateStudentForm() {
  const nameRef = useRef(null);
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([...startList]);

  const handleKeyDown = (event, nextRef) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(nextRef.current.id);

      if (nextRef.current.id !== "firstName") {
        nextRef.current.focus();
      } else {
        let myObj = {
          name: nameRef.current.value,
        };
        nameRef.current.value = '';
        let newPeople = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(people));
        newPeople.push(myObj);
        setPeople(newPeople);
        console.log(newPeople);
        nameRef.current.focus();
      }
    }
  };

  const handleDelete = (person) => {
    let newPeople = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(people));
    let idx = people.findIndex((e) => e === person);
    newPeople.splice(idx,1);
    setPeople(newPeople);
  };

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="md">
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        id="firstName"
        label="First Name"
        size="small"
        margin="normal"
        inputRef={nameRef}
        onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, nameRef)}
      />
      <Paper
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          listStyle: 'none',
          p: 0.5,
          m: 0,
        }}
        component="ul"
      >
        {people.map((data, i) => (
          <Student key={i} student={data} hDelete={handleDelete} />
        ))}
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to implement a fade-out animation when a Chip is deleted from the list. The issue you're facing is that the animation is affecting neighboring elements when you use setTimeout to wait for the animation to complete before removing the item from the list.

To resolve this, you can utilize the Transition component from react-transition-group to manage the animation states for each Chip individually. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
    import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Chip from '@mui/material/Chip';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Transition } from 'react-transition-group';

const startList = [
    { name: "Ethan Anderson" }, { name: "Olivia Brooks" }, { name: "Mason Carter" }, { name: "Ava Davis" }
];

function Student({ student, hDelete }) {
    const nodeRef = useRef(null);
    const [inProp, setIn] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIn(true);
    }, []);

    const handleDelete = () => {
        setIn(false);
    }

    const duration = 300;

    const defaultStyle = {
        transition: `opacity ${duration}ms ease-in-out`,
        opacity: 0,
    }

    const transitionStyles = {
        entering: { opacity: 1 },
        entered: { opacity: 1 },
        exiting: { opacity: 0 },
        exited: { opacity: 0 },
    };

    return (
        <Transition nodeRef={nodeRef} in={inProp} timeout={duration}>
            {state => (
                <ListItem style={{ ...defaultStyle, ...transitionStyles[state] }}>
                    <Chip
                        variant="solid"
                        size="small"
                        sx={{
                            height: 'auto',
                            '& .MuiChip-label': {
                                display: 'block',
                                whiteSpace: 'normal',
                            },
                        }}
                        label={`${student.name}`}
                        onDelete={() => {
                            handleDelete();
                            setTimeout(() => hDelete(student), duration); // Remove after animation
                        }}
                    />
                </ListItem>
            )}
        </Transition>
    )
}

const ListItem = styled('li')(({ theme }) => ({
    margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
}));

export default function CreateStudentForm() {
    const nameRef = useRef(null);
    const [people, setPeople] = useState([...startList]);

    const handleKeyDown = (event, nextRef) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (nextRef.current.id !== "firstName") {
                nextRef.current.focus();
            } else {
                let myObj = {
                    name: nameRef.current.value,
                };
                nameRef.current.value = '';
                setPeople(prevPeople => [...prevPeople, myObj]);
                nameRef.current.focus();
            }
        }
    };

    const handleDelete = (person) => {
        setPeople(prevPeople => prevPeople.filter(p => p !== person));
    };

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="md">
            <TextField
                fullWidth
                id="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                size="small"
                margin="normal"
                inputRef={nameRef}
                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, nameRef)}
            />
            <Paper
                sx={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    flexWrap: 'wrap',
                    listStyle: 'none',
                    p: 0.5,
                    m: 0,
                }}
                component="ul"
            >
                {people.map((data, i) => (
                    <Student key={i} student={data} hDelete={handleDelete} />
                ))}
            </Paper>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

In this modification, I've removed the setTimeout from handleDelete function within the Student component. Instead, the hDelete function is called immediately after setting inProp to false. This ensures that the item is removed from the list only after the fade-out animation completes for that specific Chip.

Comment: I tried running this code, and it seems to still have the same issue that it had before.  Here's a brainstorm of what I think could be wrong, and ways forward:
- Somehow the setTimeout() is getting the wrong frame reference, and when it removes the name, the tree doesn't know to update.
- I might need to push control of animation up to the CreateStudentForm() component.  I'd rather not do that.
- This also could be an issue with the libraries.

Not sure if that helps...